# Storing the names of all files with a certain extension in a folder in a string?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a folder on my webserver to which I, using a form and a PHP script allow people to upload files. I then need to use these files (xml-files) in another script. This means that I need the script to, everytime it is loaded, find all files of the extension .xml and store their names in an array.

Is this possible using Javascript (this is preferred since the script that needs all filenames is written in Javascript)? Otherwise, what is the best solution?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Javascript is executed on the page but you need script to read files on the server so that will need to be PHP. But no problem because the PHP can write the JavaScript while including its results for the string that you need.

Comment: @WilliamK Thanks a lot! I just started learning PHP (actually, I just took the upload script directly from W3Schools) and I don't really know where to look for how to do that - could you provide me with an example? :)

Comment: Just search for "list files in folder by extension using PHP".

Comment: @WilliamK Alright, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Finally managed to solve it. Heres my PHP script:

```
<?php 
$files = array();
foreach (glob("../pathtofolder/*.xml") as $file) {
  $files[] = str_replace("../guide/", "", $file);
}
echo json_encode($files);
?>
```

This is "sent" to the javascript using an XMLHttpRequest:

```
  var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
  oReq.onload = function() {
    var files = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
  };
  oReq.open("get", "phpscript.php", true);
  oReq.send();
```

The variable files now contains all filenames!